# Does anyone know of a way to customize or remove the Callout for the Fluent UI SearchBox?

Tags: search-box

I'm working on an autocomplete for the React Search Box but because it doesn't have an open interface, the Callout will popup if you have done a previous search. I want to either turn it off or customize it so I don't have to use a separate component.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late but I found setting autoComplete attribute on the SearchBox to "off" works.